# SQL simplifying an except query

Tags: sql

I have a database with around 50 million entries showing the status of a device for a given day, simplified to the form:

```
 id | status
-------------
1   | Off
1   | Off
1   | On
2   | Off
2   | Off
3   | Off
3   | Off
3   | On
...
```

such that each id is guaranteed to have at least 2 rows with an 'off' status, but doesn't have to have an 'on' status. I'm trying to get a list of only the ids that do not have an 'On' status. For example, in the above data set I'd want a query returned with only '2'

The current query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table 

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE status <> 'Off'
```

Which seems to work, but it's having to iterate over the entire table twice which ends up taking ~10-12 minutes to run per query. Is there a simpler way to do this with only a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
Select Distinct Id
From   Table  A
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Table  B
    Where   A.Id = B.Id
    And     B.Status = 'On'
)
```

I would also recommend looking at the indexes on the `Status` column.  10-12 minutes to run is excessively long.  Even with 50m records, with proper indexing, a query like this shouldn't take longer than a second.

To add an index to the column, you can run this (I'm assuming SQL Server, your syntax may vary):

```
Create NonClustered Index Ix_YourTable_Status On YourTable (Status Asc);
```

Comment: Working with this one right now; looks like adding the Where Not Exists clause is making it the query take ~75% longer than just doing the original except.

As far as why the performance is so terrible, I'm not sure. I'll look at getting an index added but I'm only supposed to be pulling data from the dbs, not modifying it.

Comment: @D.Stewart I would definitely recommend looking at the indexing of the table.  Those results don't sound quite right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation.

```
select id
from table 
group by id
having count(case when status='On' then 1 end)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the help of a SELF JOIN ..

```
         SELECT DISTINCT  A.Id
         FROM Table  A
             LEFT JOIN Table B ON A.Id=B.Id
         WHERE B.Status='On' 
                   AND B.Id IS NULL
```